# SQL/PHP - INSERT statement using PDO and data inside the table appears as 'Resource ID #'. How can I get it to store the correct string?

Tags: php, sql, insert, pdo, resources

I've been trying to figure out why this is going on.  I'm connecting to my SQL database locally and able to store some data, but for some reason this one column will not store correctly.  My SQL database has 3 columns, the first column is my Primary Key.  The first two are varchar(50), and the final one is a datetime column.

I can push values correctly to the first and third column, but for some reason it won't let me push data to the uname column correctly.  $sessionToken ends being a random number, $user SHOULD be something like "John" but ends up being Resource ID #5, and $time ends up correctly being a timestamp.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
function freshLoginSession($user) {

    try {
        $mssql = new PDO('sqlsrv:SERVERNAME;database=DATABASENAME','sa','1234');
        $sessionToken = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
        $_SESSION['loggedInToken'] = $sessionToken;
        $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.SESSION_TABLE (SESSION_KEY, UNAME, LOGIN_TIME) VALUES (:sessionToken, :user, :time)";

        $stmt = $mssql->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(':sessionToken' => $sessionToken, ':user' => $user, ':time' => $time));
        $stmt = null;
        $mssql = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: You're passing a resource, not a string, to the function. Show us where `$user` originates.

Comment: You need to check whatever's CALLING this function, where $user was defined.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Even if immediately before I call the SQL insert, I go  $user = "IMMORTAL ZOD";  I end up with a resource ID in my database.  I also tried it with a new variable.  I also tried it with the $sessionToken variable, and each time SQL stored Resource ID.

Comment: Figured it out after a few days of plugging at it.  Depricated function elsewhere was incorrectly pulling data and storing data to my SQL table.  Didn't realize the function was being called because I was trying to troubleshoot another section of code.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with PDO, as it's obviously a typo-like question featuring just lack of debugging.

Please, in a cases like this, at least echo your values out before inserting. This is a very basic thing yet one of greatest programming principles. A programmer have to check every value and then trace the wrong one up to the place where it was set.
This technique is called *debugging* and being most used programming tool.

Also, please remove these `try..catch` things from your code. they are useless and insecure.

Comment: I've done an echo on the values beforehand, and they echo out as the correct value being passed.  So if I pass 'John' as $user through my code, I echo it; it correctly displays John to the screen.  But when I insert it to my SQL DB, I get Resource ID.

Comment: Copy-paste for another response for another person trying to help: "Even if immediately before I call the SQL insert, I go $user = "IMMORTAL ZOD"; I end up with a resource ID in my database. I also tried it with a new variable. I also tried it with the $sessionToken variable, and each time SQL stored Resource ID. "